# Unable to interact with Windows file upload box with watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing a watir-webdriver test script to upload a file to app.  My application uses kendo widgets, e.g. below 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index

I am able to interact with the windows dialog box when I debug the code, but when I execute it together, it times out as the windows dialog modal never seems to get the focus. Code below:

```
require 'win32ole'

sleep 1
wsh = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')
## open the windows dialog modal.
@browser.div(:class => "k-button k-upload-button").click

### Code times out after the above click, it never executes the below steps as app looses focus,     don't  know how I can switch the focus to windows modal and execute below code.

@browser.windows.last.use do   
  sleep 2
  wsh.AppActivate("File Upload")
  sleep 2
  wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"
  sleep 1
  wsh.SendKeys("file path")
  sleep 1
  wsh.SendKeys "~"
end
```

Error :

> Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

Comment: There's no `<input type="file">` tag?  If there is, `#file_field` might do the trick.

Comment: yeah, its not there, I was able to figure the solution, by multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I was able to figure the solution for my problem by multi-threading .

 def threaded
   @filepath= upload_filepath ## reading from YAML
    t1=Thread.new { select_files }
    t2=Thread.new { file_upload(@filepath) }
    t1.join
    t2.join
  end

def select_files_click_button
    @browser.div(:class => "k-button k-upload-button").click
    sleep 2
 end

def file_upload(filepath)
  #def file_upload
    require 'win32ole'
    sleep 3
    wsh = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')
    sleep 2
    wsh.AppActivate("File Upload")
    sleep 4
    wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    sleep 3
    wsh.SendKeys("#{filepath}")
    sleep 2
    wsh.SendKeys "~"
    sleep 2
    @browser.windows.first.use
  end
```

Comment: can you explain what is WIN32OLE ?!

Comment: how can I do the same on debian (linux) ??